# Cannot Play video on device

Tags: cordova, video

I am trying to play a video on my app which i developed using PhoneGap. On normal web browsers i can play the video perfectly fine but on my device same code is returning error. Not sure where i went wrong. I am new to this technology any help or guidance will be very helpful

My code on Browser:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title> Video player</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><div style="background:cyan; width:80%; height:60%; "> 
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="http://s032.synergymms.com/SynergyWebApps/OpenFileAttachments.aspx?cid=5209&amp;fid=215" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.</source>
    </video>
</div></center>

</body>
</html>
```

On Mobile App: Phonegap

```
<video class="load-video" width="320" height="240" controls><source src="http://s032.synergymms.com/SynergyWebApps/OpenFileAttachments.aspx?cid=5209&amp;fid=215" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are developing for android? If yes, android doesn't support the  tag. Yeah, I know. So you have to use plugins to play videos. You can use https://github.com/raulduran/VideoPlayer to play your videos.Try to use the plugin, if doesn't work, I will guide you more. At the office, busy. Sorry. And btw, I was having the same problem. After 6 hours, I managed to fix it.